# Using SQL in snowflake I want to take one table's column and add that to another snowflake table based on shared join keys, but not working?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables, a stage table called: `stg_tbl` and a target table called: `target_tbl`. In `stg_tbl` there is a column called `finance_data` that I want to add to the `target_tbl`. The `target_tbl` and `stg_tbl` share two columns: `person_id, start_dt`. I want to join the finance_data column from the `stg_tbl` to the `target_tbl` based on the join keys: `person_id, start_dt`.

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT a.*, b.finance_data
FROM target_tbl AS a
LEFT JOIN stg_tbl AS b
ON a.person_id=b.person_id
AND a.start_dt=b.start_dt
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. But after I execute this and check for not null rows like so:

```
SELECT * FROM target_tbl WHERE finance_data IS NOT NULL;
```

I get zero results. So somewhere this data is not being matched/registered.

I am executing this SQL through databricks notebook and have already successfully made a connection to snowflake.

I am executing the code through a cursor like so:

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE TARGET_TBL ADD COLUMN FINANCE_DATA FLOAT")
cursor.execute("""
SELECT a.*, b.finance_data
FROM target_tbl AS a
LEFT JOIN stg_tbl AS b
ON a.person_id=b.person_id
AND a.start_dt=b.start_dt
""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to populate the newly added finance_data column in target_tbl you need to execute an UPDATE statement. Something like this:

```
UPDATE target_tbl SET finance_data=stg_tbl.finance_data
FROM stg_tbl
WHERE target_tbl.person_id=stg_tbl.person_id
AND target_tbl.start_dt=stg_tbl.start_dt
```

Comment: Thank you, when I run this it tells me that a duplicate row is detected. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: This means the combination of person_id and start_dt is not unique in stg_tbl. To address this, you need to create a temp table or define a CTE based on stg_tbl that would return only one row for each combination of person_id and start_dt, along with the finance_data value. Then you use this CTE/Temp table as a source in the query above instead of stg_tbl.

Answer (score 0):

Update statement

```
update target_tbl set finance_data=s.finance_data
from target_tbl t 
inner join stg_tbl s on s.person_id=t.person_id and s.start_dt=t.start_dt;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AgEGczKe)